# handle flask form with js

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

i have this form and script to get data from a flask api,
when i put js part in end of html page everything works fine, but when i seperate js function to new file ,after submit form new page get open with json data. i want to prevent this json page and just get data, i try defer already

```
    <form class="p-4 p-md-5 border rounded-3 bg-body-tertiary" method="post" action="{{        url_for('get_morse') }}"
                  id="morse_form">
           <div class="form-floating mb-3">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" name="text">
           <label for="floatingInput">Your Word</label>
           </div>
           <button class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary mb-3" type="submit" id="submitMorse"      onclick="get_morse()">Morse Up</button>
           <div class="form-floating mb-3">
           <p type="text" class="form-control" id="floatingMorse">{{morse_output}}</p>
           <label for="floatingMorse">Morse</label>
            </div>
            <button class="w-100  btn-sm btn btn-outline-danger mb-3" type="reset"  id="resetMorse">Reset</button>
    </form>

morseForm.addEventListener("submit",  function (e) { 
e.preventDefault();

    // Fetch morse_output from the server
     fetch('/morse', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        body: new URLSearchParams({
            'text': morseInput.value,
        }),
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            // Update the HTML content with the fetched morse_output

            morseOutput.innerText = data.morse_output

        })
        .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
});

    @app.route('/morse', methods=["POST"])
    def get_morse():
        if request.method == "POST":
            morse.reset()
            data = request.form.get("text")
            morse_output = morse.to_morse(data)
            return jsonify({"morse_output": morse_output})
```